# Visual Basic - simple 1-dimensional array with Strings giving syntax error

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an one-dimensional array with Strings and I tried this code:

```
Dim sheets_names_array() As String = { "Sheet1", "Sheet2" }
```

but I get a 'Compile error: Syntax error' when trying to run the code.

What is my error?
Many thanks,
Electra

Comment: try `Dim sheets_names_array As String` new row `sheets_names_array = array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works but now I have a hard time iterating through it :-/  do you know what is the right code to loop through it? thanks so much!

Comment: You should share a bit more code in question, as `Dim sheets_names_array() As Variant` is also possible declaration

Comment: `Dim sheets_names_array() As String
sheets_names_array = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

For Each sheet As String In sheets_names_array
   MsgBox (sheet & " ")
Next

End Sub`   the first line of the loop gives a syntax error

Comment: also, read a bit about LBound  and UBound, - these functions are very commonly used while looping through arrays.

Comment: VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) is not the same as VB.Net. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is correct example of your approach:

```
Public Sub PrintArray()

' make an array with the sheet names we want to parse
Dim sheets_names_array() As Variant, sheet As Variant

sheets_names_array = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

' loop the sheets array
For Each sheet In sheets_names_array
   Debug.Print (sheet & " ")
Next

End Sub
```

and this one is usual loop through each sheet as you declare sheet variable anyway:

```
Sub Test()

' Declare ws as a worksheet object variable.
Dim ws As Worksheet

' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
   Debug.Print ws.Name
Next

End Sub
```

P.S. not sure why SO cannot recognise the code this time...